# cannot allocate memory service systemd-networkd

Tags: linux

I encountered an issue with **`systemd-networkd`** where it failed to start the device monitor and could not create the manager due to a "Cannot allocate memory" error. I have tried restarting **`systemd-networkd`** using the command **`systemctl restart systemd-networkd`**, but the logs did not provide any helpful information. It's worth noting that I have checked the available memory using the **`free -h`** command, and it shows that I have 13Gi of available memory. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on understanding this error and resolving the issue. Additionally, if there are any specific troubleshooting steps or configurations that I should check, please let me know. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.